# How to read numbers from a byte-array saved in C++ in Java?

Tags: java, c++, binaryfiles, unsigned-integer

I have a binary file generated by a C++ app. I need to read it in Java.

Here are the C++ writing methods:

```
inline void write_static<unsigned int>(std::ofstream & bofs, const unsigned int value)
{
    bofs.put ((value) & 0xff);
    bofs.put ((value >> 8) & 0xff);
    bofs.put ((value >> 16) & 0xff);
    bofs.put ((value >> 24) & 0xff);
}

inline void write_static<float>(std::ofstream & bofs, const float value)
{
    unsigned int x;
    memcpy(&x, &value, sizeof(x));
    write_static<unsigned int>(bofs, x);
}
```

String data are simply saved like this:

```
char character[16];
std::strncpy(character, col[0], sizeof(character));
bofs.write(character, sizeof(character));
```

No magic with bytes order here.

I managed to write methods in java which partially solve the problem:

```
private static int getInt(byte[] bytes) {
    int result = (bytes[offset]) | (bytes[offset+1] << 8) | (bytes[offset+2] << 16) | (bytes[offset+3] << 24);
    offset +=4;
    return result;
}

public static long getUnsignedInt(byte[] bytes) {
    int res = (bytes[offset]) | (bytes[offset+1] << 8) | (bytes[offset+2] << 16) | (bytes[offset+3] << 24);
    long result = res & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
    offset += 4;
    return result;
}

private static float getFloat(byte[] bytes) {
    float result = (bytes[offset]) | (bytes[offset+1] << 8) | (bytes[offset+2] << 16) | (bytes[offset+3] << 24);
    offset +=4;
    return result;
}

private static String getString(byte[] bytes) {
    bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, offset, offset + 16);
    offset += 16;
    return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

String data is rendered fine. So, it seems that did not mess up the offsets. But the problem is that in many cases `getInt()` returns wrong values. When it happens the value is signed negative. I guess it is due to the original `int` being `unsigned` and thus the leftmost bit being treated as the sign bit. So, I tried to save the value into `long`. But the `getUnsignedInt()` method returning a `long` value also does not seem to return correct values in these particular cases. Otherwise it returns exactly the same values as `getInt()`.

Also, it seems to me that `getFloat()` also returns rubbish. I'm currently trying to find info on how the values are stored in memory for both languages, but it is quite a pain to figure everything out. Maybe somebody with more experience could help me out.

Comment: Can you be more specific what value of long for unsigned ints is not "correct"?

Comment: Some examples for getInt / getUnsignedInt issue would make things a lot easier. The constructor to getString does not need to copy the byte[], just return as `new String(bytes, offset, offset + 16, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `float` method at least should be something like this (not tested or compiled):

```
private static float getFloat(byte[] bytes) {
    int f = getInt( bytes );
    return Float.intBitsToFloat( f );
}
```

If you can be more specific about what the problem with unsigned `int`s is, we might be able to fix that too.

For longer term maintainability, you might consider using `DataInputstream` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html